# How to access files via Powershell with [ and ] characters in the name?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder of files which have [ and ] in the name and I am trying to access these files to read their content via Powershell.

Example file:
Data.Service[SERVER].1.2023-08-03_11@28.log

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $logFolder *.log)

    foreach ($f in $files){
      echo $f
      foreach($line in Get-Content -Path $files.FullName.Substring($logFolder.Length)){
        echo $line
      }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:
Get-Content : An object at the specified path \Data.Service[SERVER].1.2023-08-03_11@28.log does
not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.

When I change the name of the filename, the code is working.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Try: [`Get-Content -LiteralPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content#-literalpath)